# The .svn directory was accessible

Tags: svn

The /.svn directory was accessible on my website, that is. it was possible to download all files in the "/.svn" directory

Example:

```
http: //test.com/.svn/pristine/* ...
http://test.com/.svn/wc.db
```

Is it possible to obtain the source code of my repository through these files?

What kind of information is stored in "svn/pristine/*" and "wc.db" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.svn` directory contains the complete metadata of your Subversion working copy. So, yes, you've essentially published your entire codebase. Given an empty directory with a downloaded copy of `.svn`, you can reconstruct the actual files with the [revert subcommand](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.revert.html):

```sh
$ svn revert path/to/parent/folder --recursive
```

... where *path/to/parent/folder* is the folder that contains the `.svn` subdirectory.

Additionally, if the repository is open to the internet and is not password-protected they'll also have access to the complete history because the working copy contains repository URL (but that'd be a problem on its own).

Last but not least, I hope you don't commit passwords into Subversion. But if you do so, you should be changing them all.

Comment: I do not understand what is the meaning of “rehydrate” here.

Comment: @bahrep Now I think about it, it's a metaphor that went out of control. I'll rephrase it.